# Slow speed for UFS mounted drive in Linux

Tags: mount, sun, ufs, write

I have a disk that has Sun OS disk, (ufs filesystem). And I want to mount it in my debain machine with read/write mode. Since by deafult linux doesn't support write to ufs filesystem. I had to recompile the kernel by setting to the flag CONFIG_UFS_FS_WRITE=y. Now I am able to write to the filesystem, but the read/write speed is very slow. It is around 120 KB/s. Any idea what is wrong and how to resolve this issue?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: This is a plain hard drive, or a USB drive?

Answer (score 1):

From what [I can find](http://blog.julipedia.org/2004/11/linuxs-ufs-support.html), UFS support seemed to be problematic and/or unreliable in Linux. Most of the articles I found were from years ago.

You didn't say whether this was a USB drive or an actual hard disk, and one thing some recommended was to check your USB speed.

Another option might be to use virtualization or a bootable disk to run a variant of FreeBSD, which should natively support UFS. I don't know if you're just looking to get files off the drive or if you are trying to share the drive with another system, but if you're just looking to pull data, using a bootable *BSD variant may be the best go-between. Or you can set up a BSD VM or small BSD machine to act as a SAMBA server so you can read and write with that filesystem.

Comment: It is an actual hard disk. And since it is SAS disk, the speed mentioned is 3Gb/s. 

Working with SAMBA server will have network bottleneck, since file to be worked with are of the size of 100GBs. So, I tried a normal ext3 filesystem disk over the network with nfs, and network is the bottleneck over there. So, can there be any other solution to this?

Comment: So the situation is that you have an SAS disk drive with UFS filesystem with files you're trying to access that are 100's of gigabytes in size, and accessing them over the network causes a bottleneck from the network. If you're the only one using them, and if they're important (which from that size, what are they? Video? Graphics?), I'd consider getting another drive, install, format with a native fs, then copy those files once from the UFS disk over either from a share or with scp. Or borrow a temp drive to copy over to then reformat the UFS drive and copy back.

Comment: Basically I'd look at finding a way to take that data and transfer it to another disk with a native filesystem once and work with it from there. You could even probably use dragonflyBSD to temporarily copy data from one drive to another.

Comment: Yeah, finally I got another drive with native fileystem, since I couldn't think of a better solution.

They are Graphics related files.

Also, do you have any idea, how to make make a ufs filesystem from linux machine. I have a debian lenny, and it doesn't seem to have mkfs.ufs in it. Neither I can find ufsutils in the debian mirror. Any other idea?

Comment: ufs-modules? http://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=ufs&searchon=names&suite=stable&section=all